# Qt: Animating QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qpixmap

The answer code is located here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50550471/4962676):
https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/50550089

The answer was more simple than the code below - the code above uses QPropertyAnimation rather than using for loops with QThread like below - which saves tons of space in the code and is more efficient.

Original question below:

I am writing an application in Qt and I am having an issue with closing the application and the threads.

Basically, the application window closes, however the process remains in the background and never closes.

my main header (just included the class since there are a lot of includes):

```
class ChatUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit ChatUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~ChatUI();

    private:
        // The UI itself
        Ui::ChatUI * ui;

        // Current appliation startup directory
        QString applicationStartupDir = QDir::currentPath() + "/";

        // Typing indicator stuff
        QFrame * typingIndicator = nullptr;
        QImage circleImage;
        ThreadController * typingIndicatorThread = new ThreadController(false);
        bool currentlyFadingTypingIndicator = false;

        // The calm before the storm
        bool closing = false;

        void showTypingIndicator();
        void hideTypingIndicator();
    signals:
        void WidgetClosed();

    protected:
        void closeEvent(QCloseEvent*);
};
```

my controller (header):

```
#ifndef THREADCONTROLLER_H
#define THREADCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QImage>
#include <QFrame>

#include "typingindicatorthread.h"

class ThreadController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread * workerThread = nullptr;
    TypingIndicatorThread * worker = nullptr;
signals:
    void startWork(QFrame*, QImage);
    //void killThread();
public slots:
    void killThread();
public:
    ThreadController(bool);
};

#endif // THREADCONTROLLER_H
```

my controller (source):

```
#include "threadcontroller.h"
#include <QDebug>

ThreadController::ThreadController(bool asd)
{
    if (asd == true){
        workerThread = new QThread();

        worker = new TypingIndicatorThread;
        worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
        workerThread->start();

        connect(this, &ThreadController::startWork, worker, &TypingIndicatorThread::startWorker);
    } else {
        workerThread = new QThread();
        workerThread->quit();
        workerThread->wait();

        delete workerThread;
    }
}

void ThreadController::killThread() {
    emit worker->killSignal();

    workerThread->quit();
    workerThread->wait();
}
```

My thread (header):

```
#ifndef TYPINGINDICATORTHREAD_H
#define TYPINGINDICATORTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

class TypingIndicatorThread : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ~TypingIndicatorThread();
private:
    bool kill = false;
public slots:
    void startWorker(QFrame*, QImage);
    void killSignal();
};

#endif // TYPINGINDICATORTHREAD_H
```

my thread (source):

```
#include "typingindicatorthread.h"
#include <QDebug>

inline void delay(int millisecondsWait)
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer t;
    t.connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    t.start(millisecondsWait);
    loop.exec();
}

void TypingIndicatorThread::startWorker(QFrame * typingIndicator, QImage circleImage) {
    int max = 30;
    int min = 5;
    int waitTime = 5;

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(typingIndicator, [=]() {
        QLabel * circle1 = new QLabel(typingIndicator);
        circle1->setGeometry(0,0, 50, 50);
        circle1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        circle1->show();

        QLabel * circle2 = new QLabel(typingIndicator);
        circle2->setGeometry(40,0, 50, 50);
        circle2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        circle2->show();

        QLabel * circle3 = new QLabel(typingIndicator);
        circle3->setGeometry(80,0, 50, 50);
        circle3->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        circle3->show();

        forever {
            if (kill) {
                qDebug() << "Killing thread";

                return;
            }

            // Circle1
            for (int i=min; i < max; i++) {
                delay(waitTime);

                QPixmap circlePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(circleImage).scaled(QSize(i, i), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

                circle1->setPixmap(circlePixmap);
            }

            for (int i=max; i > min; i--) {
                delay(waitTime);

                QPixmap circlePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(circleImage).scaled(QSize(i, i), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

                circle1->setPixmap(circlePixmap);
            }

            // Circle2
            for (int i=min; i < max; i++) {
                delay(waitTime);

                QPixmap circlePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(circleImage).scaled(QSize(i, i), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

                circle2->setPixmap(circlePixmap);
            }

            for (int i=max; i > min; i--) {
                delay(waitTime);

                QPixmap circlePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(circleImage).scaled(QSize(i, i), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

                circle2->setPixmap(circlePixmap);
            }

            // Circle3
            for (int i=min; i < max; i++) {
                delay(waitTime);

                QPixmap circlePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(circleImage).scaled(QSize(i, i), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

                circle3->setPixmap(circlePixmap);
            }

            for (int i=max; i > min; i--) {
                delay(waitTime);

                QPixmap circlePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(circleImage).scaled(QSize(i, i), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

                circle3->setPixmap(circlePixmap);
            }
        }
    });
}

void TypingIndicatorThread::killSignal() {
    qDebug() << "oh no we are going to the shadow realm";

    kill = true;
}

TypingIndicatorThread::~TypingIndicatorThread() {
    emit killSignal();
}
```

The only reason why I am using messy for-loops for my animation is because I researched as much as possible into animating images, however there is nothing to make an animation outside of QML and the application is in c++.

If possible it would be great to use QPropertyAnimation as an alternative, but I can't seem to animate the size of the bubbles (circles) while at the same time updating the size it displays.

I apologize if this is a lot of code, I just wanted to give as much context as possible (and that is relevant) to help solve this issue.

Comment: You could explain what kind of animation you want, I think that should be your real question.

Comment: I'd want to animate the scale (height/width) of the image - that way I can make it transition from being small to big or reverse.

Comment: okay I understand you, you could show the file chatui.cpp

Comment: That file is around 500 lines long, what specific parts do you want to see? Specifically how I use the classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use `QThread` to make an animation, for this Qt offers the class `QPropertyAnimation`, and if you want the animation to be sequential you must use `QSequentialAnimationGroup`

In the case of `QLabel` you must set the `scaledContents` to true so that the `QPixmap` is the same size as the `QLabel`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSequentialAnimationGroup>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFrame frame;
    frame.resize(320, 240);
    QSequentialAnimationGroup group;
    group.setLoopCount(-1);
    int minSize = 5;
    int maxSize = 30;
    int labelSize = 50;;
    for(const QPoint & pos: {QPoint(0, 0), QPoint(0, 40), QPoint(0, 80)}){
        QRect startVal = QRect(pos + (QPoint(labelSize, labelSize) + QPoint(-minSize, -minSize))/2 , QSize(minSize, minSize));
        QRect endVal = QRect(pos + (QPoint(labelSize, labelSize) + QPoint(-maxSize, -maxSize))/2 , QSize(maxSize, maxSize));
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(&frame);
        label->setGeometry(startVal);
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/circle.png"));
        label->setScaledContents(true);
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "geometry");
        animation->setStartValue(startVal);
        animation->setKeyValueAt(.5, endVal);
        animation->setEndValue(startVal);
        animation->setDuration(1000);
        group.addAnimation(animation);
    }
    group.start();
    frame.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

You can find the complete code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50550089)

[image]

Comment: This doesn't lock the UI thread? So I can continue to interact with it?

Comment: @Jacob the QXXXAnimations do not block the GUI, they are friendly with the Qt event loop, for that they were created.

Comment: @Jacob : Of course it doesn't, because there is no extra work related to the animation in your code - the event loop does it all, and the UI is kept responsive.

Comment: One more thing - is it possible to animate fixed size? I might have to use a layout to position the images correctly. My issue is that the images are off-center when re-sized due to the label size changing. I need it to be centered when sizing if possible.

Comment: @Jacob 
Explain better, those labels also have text. a QLabel can only have text or QPixmap, not the 2 things.

Comment: @Jacob I see the images centered, what is the problem?

Comment: Oh I misread the code - let me try implementing it correctly. I upvoted the post for now before accepting it.

Comment: Is there a way to make them execute in a certain order rather than at the same time?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, use QSequentialAnimationGroup instead of QParallelAnimationGroup, I have updated my answer.

Comment: This was more of the effect I was looking for if this helps - https://youtu.be/-fDLqlpbkII?t=24s

Comment: @Jacob 
Okay, I understand where I should correct it, but on the other hand, do you want the Circle to be enlarged with respect to the upper left corner?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means, but basically it will be placed into a frame with the size of 130, 50 and be positioned accordingly in there

Comment: @Jacob 
Check my answer again, look at the image you put, is that the effect you want?

Comment: Yes that's the effect I want in your image.

Comment: @Jacob 
I recommend you change the title of your question and give more space in the content of your question to your real requirement. Do not eliminate the threads but put it as an attempt. :)

Comment: @Jacob 
We have saved a lot of code by passing it from QThread to QAnimation. :)

Comment: Changed the title and added the answer with clarification to the post. Thank you so much!

Comment: Github link is dead

Comment: @skillz21 Fixed link